# Pra que serve o ActionBarSherlock pro Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Um ex-colega utilizou esse framework/lib não sei em um projeto da empresa pra Android e restringiu a versão para android 4.0+, porém precisamos que rode em Android versão 2.3+... sendo assim não vejo opção se não retirar esse negócio. Notei que todas as activities tem uma segunda classe chamada NomeActivity_, terrível isso.

Estou usando algumas anotações que me parecem que são deles com o @click para atribuir uma função a um botão, nada que um método devolvendo um listener não resolva.

Então afinal, pra que serve esse framework? o que ele faz de bom pelo projeto? no Site eu vi que ele seria apenas uma forma de adicionar actionBar no projeto, mas nem isso usamos... tem alguma utilidade esse negócio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essas anotações não são do **ActionBarSherlock** e sim do **Android Annotations**.

A **ActionBarSherlock** é responsável por oferecer uma implementação de compatibilidade da `ActionBar` para dispositivos com versão de Android menor que 3.0. Atualmente a biblioteca `appcompat` já fornece essa implementação de compatibilidade, não sendo mais necessário usar o **ActionBarSherlock**. Além disso o próprio `ActionBar` está entrando em desuso a favor do `Toolbar` da versão 5.0, que o `appcompat` também fornece compatibilidade.

---

A biblioteca **Android Annotations** adiciona algumas anotações, que servem como atalhos para determinadas ações, funcionalidades e declarações, que em geral reduzem a quantidade de código escrito redundante e repetitivo ("boilerplate"). A maior vantagem dita pelos criadores da biblioteca seria o aumento da produtividade.

Exemplo:

```
@ViewById -> chama o findViewById da Activity após o setContentView
@EActivity -> chama o setContentView com o id especificado na anotação
```

O uso dessa biblioteca tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, depende muito de cada projeto/equipe.

O sufixo `_` na `NomeActivity_` é um efeito colateral, porque para cada classe anotada, por exemplo `NomeActivity`, gera uma classe nova com esse sufixo, com todo o código auto-gerado respectivo a cada uma dessas anotações.

Essas funções a princípio não causam impacto em performance, pois todo código extra é gerado em tempo de compilação, mas pode ser que o código não seja o mais otimizado (as vezes isso nem importa em prol da legibilidade/produtividade).

Você pode olhar na pasta `gen` do *Eclipse* ou busca-lá usando o `Ctrl-R` ou `Ctrl-T` e ver o código auto-gerado.

No caso do *Android Studio*, acredito que você precisa ir `target/generated-sources/annotations` e verá o código gerado.

Para mais detalhes: http://androidannotations.org

---

Sobre a versão, as duas bibliotecas suportam o Android 2.3. Sugiro você fazer o levantamento de quais bibliotecas o projeto tem e verificar no AndroidManifest delas quais as versões elas colocaram como mínimo.

Caso não tenha nenhuma, recomendo fazer um teste/análise bem criteriosa no código pois podem haver chamadas a API de versões mais novas que irão gerar erro em tempo de execução (alguns o lint pode ser alertar em tempo de compilação). E.g: API de animação (ObjectAnimator, ValueAnimator, ViewPropertyAnimator e etc...).